# XSLT - Recursing metadata keyed elements

Tags: xslt-3.0

I'm using the XSLT v3 capability to transform json to XML. Assuming I get the resulting standard transformation injected into an XML "metadata" node, I'd like to render the information in html using XSLT. How do I recurse the map elements to isolate the individual object name "MyClass" and it's properties - "myName", "myAddress", and their associated types - "string", "number" etc...

```
<metadata>
    <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <string key="type">object</string>
        <map key="properties">
            <map key="MyClass">
                <string key="type">array</string>
                <map key="items">
                    <string key="type">object</string>
                    <map key="properties">
                       <map key="myName">
                           <string key="type">string</string>
                       </map>
                       <map key="myAddress">
                           <string key="type">string</string>
                       </map>
                       <map key="myAge">
                           <string key="type"number</string>
                       </map>
                    </map>
                </map>
             </map>
          </map>
       </map>
    </map>
</metadata>
```

Comment: Which HTML do you want to create for that XML sample? Recursion in XSLT when processing XML is usually done simply by `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much what HTML output you want to produce. You could do it, for example, using

```
<xsl:template match="fn:string">
  <p>{string-join(ancestor-or-self::*/@key, '/')} = {.}</p>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Recursive descent of the input document using `xsl:apply-templates` is very much the normal way of processing in XSLT, whether the input data is actually recursive or not.